# How to exclude from match if a substring of another string

Tags: regex

I have a problem. I'd like to match all occurrences of \t in my text (and by \t i mean it literally it is not a tab character) but I would like to exclude a match if it is a part of \t string. How to do that?

Example

```
<HTML>Blah</HTML>\t
D:\\UserData\\tui
```

I'd like to match \t in the first line but not in second line (as it is a
part of \\t).

Is this at all possible using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\\t\b/
```

`\b` matches a word boundary (transition from word-like character to non-word-like, or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

You have to define more precisely what you mean by "part of a string".  For example, you might mean: Don't match \t if it is followed by more alphanumerics or slash.  So that would become (in Perl):

```
  \\t(?![\w\\])
```

Comment: Simply put. My regular expression is now \\t.
But I don't want any matches in following text.

D:\\UserData\\tui

Comment: Then your regular expression is **not** simply \\t.  Because \\t matches in your text.  Adrian's point is you need to come up with a hard and fast *rule* for deciding whether an occurrence of "\t" should be considered a match or not.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to define in exactly which cases a \t should match, and in which ones it shouldn't, before it's possible to determine a regex for it. Your current definition seems to be of the "I'll know it when I see it" variety, which is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Match anything but a backslash, match a backslash and match a "t" character.

```
/[^\\](\\t)/
```